# How to keep the items in a text file that "partially" occur twice using grep or sed or...?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a huge list with +100000 items that partially occur twice.
The first part of each string has a fixed length (in my example 12), the second and the third part (if present) of the same string can be different in length. The parts are divided by a colon.

Example:

```
000188741550:michael:NY
000284557650:bob:CALIFORNIA
000284557650:ester:UTAH
000284601600:david
000284601600
000314885220:david
```

I'd like to keep the items of which the first part occurs twice (or remove those that occur only once)

Result:

```
000284557650:bob:CALIFORNIA
000284557650:ester:UTAH
000284601600:david
000284601600
```

Is there any way to use `grep` or `sed` (I use gnuwin) to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is:

cat my_file|cut -d: -f1|sort| uniq -d > duplicated_ids

And after that, use grep or fgrep to retrieve original records:

fgrep -f duplicated_ids my_file

However I don't know if fgrep , sort, cut are available on gnuwin.

Comment: superb! didn't had to change a thing! Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Glad you made it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F: '{cnt[$1]++; map[$1]=map[$1] $0 RS} END{for (key in map) if (cnt[key]>1) printf "%s",map[key]}' file
000284557650:bob:CALIFORNIA
000284557650:ester:UTAH
000284601600:david
000284601600
```